# Extjs Show tooltip on entire grid row insted of cell basis

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am new in extjs and i am using version 3.2.I am trying to show tooltip on mouseover of row.

My code is like this

```
{header: "remarks",
    width: 120,
    sortable: true,
    dataIndex: 'remarks',
    renderer: function (value,metadata) {
             return  getToolTip(value,metadata);
        } ,
         editor: {
             xtype: 'textfield',
             allowBlank: true
             }},

function getToolTip(value, metadata, record){
                    metadata.attr = 'ext:qtip="' + value + '"';
                   return value;
                }
```

Its working fine when i mouseover on remarks coloumn.What i want tooltip with remarks value will show for entire row mouseover.

How to acheive this

Please Help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must change 'ext-qtip' to 'data-qtip'

Comment: That was introduced after 4.x, in 3.x it's still `ext:qtip`.